# Seaborn doesn't locate the data even though I imported it correctly

Tags: python, seaborn, valueerror

I'm trying to make a scatterplot using seaborn in a Collab enviroment, the thing is that when I'm running the cell corresponding to the graph it shows:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret value 'fahrenheit' for parameter 'y'
```

I've tried using a different laptop and it works there!
Also I've tried updating seaborn in my cmd and running the program in JupyterNotebook, but seems impossible. Has anyone had a symilar problem? How did you solve it?

The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
datos = pd.read_csv("celsius.csv")
sb.scatterplot(x = "celsius", y = "fahrenheit", data = datos, hue = "fahrenheit", palette = "coolwarm")
```

And yes, I've checked that the fahrenheit column does exist in the data.

I've tried updating seaborn, checking that the column does exist, run the code on a different computer, and tried different enviroments in mine.

Comment: Please provide sample data and in a [minimal and reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391). Otherwise people won't be able to test.

Comment: Did you check  the data type for column `fahrenheit`?

Comment: A common problem is the column name having extra spaces. Try `print(datos.colums)`.  Could you also check the seaborn and pandas version numbers on both computers? Preferably, you try upgrading to the latest.